# Advice for exploiting Sucker Reputation

Tags: poker-strategy, psychology

I play in a regular cash game with pretty much the same people every week.  I tend to play pretty tight and rarely loosen up, as the game is pretty crazy.  It is typically not a problem getting money into a pot.

Because I play pretty tight, and there are nights I fold, fold, fold and I am kind of seen as a sucker.  Without getting into too much detail I tend to win more often then I lose, and when I lose it tends to be much smaller then when I win.

One of my favorite players is a guy with a huge ego.  To reinforce this matter he got a lot of TV time during his first main event and cashed, yet he is quite terrible.  He is often a large profit center for me (and others).  He is the main person that designates me as a sucker.

Last night I caught myself trying to correct his classification of me.  Wrong.  I should be trying to exploit this to extract more profit.  While his ego could probably not be penetrated, others could change their minds about me.  Instead I want to reinforce the image, I think, in order to extract the most money.

Any ideas on this front?

Comment: You say the game is pretty crazy and you have no problem getting money in the pot so why adjust? Just sit tight until they adjust to you.

Answer (score 1):

so the profit center guy sees you as a sucker because in his opinion you are playing way to tight, right? If thats the case, the guy won´t expect you to bluff that often, so bluff more often when you are in a pot with him etc...

I would like to have a seat to his right and would add some hands to my opening range to play IP with him. If he is aware of your postflop play, there are tons of options to be creative.

E.g. If you open preflop on the BTN and he calls in the BB, you flop TPTK, bet the flop and get called, try to check the hand down. He´ll assume that you only bet turn and river with a monster and so on...

But please dont overthink things. Most of the time its much better to play straighforward.

Hope that helps.

Gl at the tables